# Mysql 5.6 Installation errors in Mac M1

Tags: mysql, homebrew, apple-m1, mysql-5.6

System version - macOS Monterey (12.4)
Chip - Apple M1 Pro

**Objective** - I want to install mysql@5.6 using brew as per requirement. Any other methods are also welcomed.

Steps followed -

1. run command for installing mysql 5.6 (brew install mysql@5.6)

```bash
Warning: mysql@5.6 has been deprecated because it is not supported upstream!
Error: mysql@5.6: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source mysql@5.6
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels
```

2. run prompted command (brew install --build-from-source mysql@5.6)

```bash
Warning: mysql@5.6 has been deprecated because it is not supported upstream!
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/cmake/manifests/3.23.2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/cmake/blobs/sha256:46711ae9d567064916561c472b94cba0e939ae72479f6f51ebe98dc6995c4422
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:46711ae9d567064916561c472b94cba0e939ae72479f6f51ebe98dc6995c4422?se=2022-07-04T12%3A45%3A00Z&sig=PNUycLoV8sRSiCs2K38VapK1SXcIrE%2######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.51.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.51.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.4.

==> Installing dependencies for mysql@5.6: cmake
==> Installing mysql@5.6 dependency: cmake
==> Pouring cmake--3.23.2.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2: 3,043 files, 42.2MB
==> Installing mysql@5.6
==> Patching
==> cmake . -DCOMPILATION_COMMENT=Homebrew -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DINSTALL_DOCDIR=share/doc/mysql@5.6 -DINSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include/mysql -DINSTALL_INFODIR=share/info -DINSTALL_M==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/amangautam/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql@5.6/02.make:
[  9%] Building C object extra/libevent/CMakeFiles/event.dir/evrpc.c.o
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_LIBEVENT2 -DHAVE_TLSv13 -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent/include -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent/compat -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/include -isystem /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/zlib -fPIC -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Qunused-arguments -O3 -DNDEBUG -DDBUG_OFF -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -MD -MT extra/libevent/CMakeFiles/event.dir/evrpc.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/event.dir/evrpc.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evrpc.c.o -c /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent/evrpc.c
[  9%] Linking C static library lib/libevent_extra.a
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc lib/libevent_extra.a CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/buffer.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_filter.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_pair.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_ratelim.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_sock.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/event.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evmap.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evutil.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evutil_rand.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evutil_time.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/listener.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/log.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/signal.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/strlcpy.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/select.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/poll.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/kqueue.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evthread_pthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/event_tagging.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/http.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evdns.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evrpc.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib lib/libevent_extra.a
[  9%] Built target event_extra
[  9%] Linking C static library lib/libevent.a
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/event.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-17683-15afkyt/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/event.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc lib/libevent.a CMakeFiles/event.dir/buffer.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_filter.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_pair.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_ratelim.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_sock.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/event.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evmap.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evutil.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evutil_rand.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evutil_time.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/listener.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/log.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/signal.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/strlcpy.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/select.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/poll.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/kqueue.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evthread_pthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/event_tagging.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/http.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evdns.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evrpc.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib lib/libevent.a
[  9%] Built target event
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.4.

Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels.
```

3. As per above response, I did system update and again ran same command (brew install --build-from-source mysql@5.6)

```bash
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
editorconfig-checker

Warning: mysql@5.6 has been deprecated because it is not supported upstream!
==> Downloading https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.51.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/amangautam/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/050b4768f405f6217eaccbda4b2f0c5ba8ded872cf62408677fcf7883cfe82ea--mysql-5.6.51.tar.gz
==> Patching
==> cmake . -DCOMPILATION_COMMENT=Homebrew -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DINSTALL_DOCDIR=share/doc/mysql@5.6 -DINSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include/mysql -DINSTALL_INFODIR=share/info -DINSTALL_M
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/amangautam/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql@5.6/02.make:
[  9%] Building C object extra/libevent/CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evrpc.c.o
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_LIBEVENT2 -DHAVE_TLSv13 -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent/include -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent/compat -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent -I/tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/include -isystem /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/zlib -fPIC -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Qunused-arguments -O3 -DNDEBUG -DDBUG_OFF -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -MD -MT extra/libevent/CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evrpc.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evrpc.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evrpc.c.o -c /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent/evrpc.c
[  9%] Linking C static library lib/libevent_extra.a
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc lib/libevent_extra.a CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/buffer.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_filter.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_pair.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_ratelim.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/bufferevent_sock.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/event.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evmap.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evutil.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evutil_rand.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evutil_time.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/listener.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/log.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/signal.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/strlcpy.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/select.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/poll.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/kqueue.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evthread_pthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/event_tagging.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/http.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evdns.c.o CMakeFiles/event_extra.dir/evrpc.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib lib/libevent_extra.a
[  9%] Built target event_extra
[  9%] Linking C static library lib/libevent.a
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/event.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/mysqlA5.6-20220704-3462-1u6glir/mysql-5.6.51/extra/libevent && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/event.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc lib/libevent.a CMakeFiles/event.dir/buffer.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_filter.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_pair.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_ratelim.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/bufferevent_sock.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/event.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evmap.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evutil.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evutil_rand.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evutil_time.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/listener.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/log.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/signal.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/strlcpy.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/select.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/poll.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/kqueue.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evthread_pthread.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/event_tagging.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/http.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evdns.c.o CMakeFiles/event.dir/evrpc.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib lib/libevent.a
[  9%] Built target event
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels.
```

getting the same make error. I searched on google but not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to install a deprecated package that won't be translated to the M1 architecture, my recommendation is to use Rosetta to install it.

You can follow the steps [here](https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development/) to setup a terminal running with Rosetta.

You'll know you're in a Rosetta terminal when you get `i386` when running the `arch` command in your terminal.

Perform the installation steps there using homebrew. Please note the slightly different installation folder when installing with a Rosetta terminal vs native terminal.

The service should run using `brew services start mysql@5.6`.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron T for mentioning the blog link. I uninstalled the brew from `arm64` and reinstalled it using Rosetta terminal and that worked